# Bind function in UIButtons created programmatically in a loop

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit

I have a API that returns me a lot of images and pdf files and I have to render it in a UIScrollView and have a button so the user can download this image/file

The content of the UIScrollView is just a UIView that I actually add the views created by API response

The problem is that only the first button I create actually calls the function that was binded, the other ones just do nothing

The structure is like this

- UIScrollView

  - UIView

    - Content generated by code

I generate the buttons in this way:

```swift
for item in items {
  let view = UIView()
  // set view width and height constraints
  // ...

  let button = UIButton()
  button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  button.backgroundColor = .red
  button.setTitle("download", for: .normal)
  button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
  button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true

  // bind function
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(download(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

  view.addSubview(button)
  button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
  button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true

  content.addSubview(view)
  // set views constraints to the bottom of the last subview
  // ...
}
```

And `download` function it's just a function with a print:

```swift
@objc func download(_ sender: UIButton) {
  print("download button clicked")
}
```

I have already tryied use `addAction` instead of `addTarget` but it didn't work either

```swift
button.addAction(UIAction { _ in
  print("download button clicked")
}, for: .touchUpInside)
```

The same thing happened when I create 3 fixed buttons outside the loop

How can I do to make all the buttons bind the function correctly?

ps.: I'm kinda new to Swift and iOS programming in general, also I'm not english fluent so I'm sorry for mistakes

Comment: Are you saying that when you tap on the 2nd (or 3rd, etc.) button that you don't see the print statement from your `download` function? That you only see the print when the 1st button is tapped?

Comment: @HangarRash yes, only the first button print when tapped

Comment: Use Xcode's "Debug View Hierarchy" feature and make sure the buttons aren't being clipped or covered. That would prevent the taps from being recognized.

Comment: @HangarRash I've find out the problem: the UIView where I add the buttons it's not growing with its content, even if the scroll is working fine

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found out looking at `Debug View Hierarchy` that the UIView where I was adding this new views with the button was not growing as I added content

What I had to do was create a height constraint and increase it everytime I add a new view

Like this:

```swift
var contentHeightConstraing: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
  contentHeightConstraint = content.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
  contentHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
}
```

And when I add a new view:

```swift
var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
for subview in content.subviews {
  contentHeight += subview.frame.height
}
contentHeightConstraint?.constant = contentHeight
```